# WheelView in Robotium

Tags: android, robotium

I downloaded wheel view android project. i want to test that wheel view using robotium. Its possible to test using robotium. any one can help me?

Answer (score 0):

There's no official document on how to use the solo with wheel view.
You can test your application with the robotium and programmatic handle the wheel view during the test.

I also suggest you to ask this question in robotium [issue](http://code.google.com/p/robotium/issues/list) page